# Android UDP сервер не принимает сообщения

Tags: android, udp

Никак не получается запустить UPD сервер. Порт открывается, никаких ошибок и исключений не выдает, но ничего не принимает. Вообще нужен бродкаст, но не работает никак. Ни адресно, ни широковещательно.
Вводные такие:
API: 29
Разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Функция

```
private fun startServerSocket() {
    Thread(Runnable {
        var stringData: String? = null
        val msg = ByteArray(1000)
        var dp = DatagramPacket(msg, msg.size)
        var ds: DatagramSocket? = null
        try {
            ds = DatagramSocket(9230)
            //ds = DatagramSocket(9230, InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"))
            while (true) {
                ds.receive(dp)
                stringData = String(msg, 0, dp.length)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        finally {
            ds?.close()
        }
    }).start()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

В описании метода сказано, что в том виде, в котором его используете вы, он доступен только на той машине, на которой выполняется данный код. Что логично, поскольку в этом случае не указан IP интерфейса, на котором следует слушать порт. Вы не сможете обратиться к нему извне.
Для привязки к сетевому интерфейсу используйте:

```
ds = DatagramSocket(9230, InetAddress.getByAddress(byte[]{192, 168, 50, 100}))
```

где {192, 168, 50, 100} - IP-адрес одного (того, на который вы собираетесь принимать броадкасты) из сетевых интерфейсов вашего устройства.

Comment: Так тоже не работает.